# Cannot see Application server in Tomcat Server

Tags: intellij-idea

I am building a web app from scratch in Intellij Ultimate version, I can see there the Tomcat and EE is enabled in plugin, as per below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvVbS.png)

but when I go to Add configuration, the Application server is blank, and cannot see either when click the dropdown list, does that mean I dont have tomcat installed:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6lGO.png)

anyone else had the similar issue?

Comment: Seems you don't have servers configured. Please click on "Configure" and add server.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have tried that, but I don't see any tomcat library. According to JetBrain, IntelliJ ultimate version does have tomcat integrated once installed:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/application-servers-support.html but not too sure why I cant see it.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed with JetBrain that Integration for tomcat is pre-installed in the IntelliJ IDE. However the Tomcat itself - is not. Thus, I need to download Tomcat from  https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi and define the path in IntelliJ IDEA. All good now, I had configured my tomcat and working as expected now.